# jQuery simplified multiple div mouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mouseover

Not sure my title is accurate or not. For some reasons, I need to apply different id for the class, because it only detects id but not class when I hover it. So I have did a css version where when my mouse hover the div, the opacity of the certain div will go to 1.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-01">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-1"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here.</p>
          <a class="btn-primary"" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-02">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-2"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here.</p>
          <a class="btn-primary"" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-03">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-3"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 3</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here</p>
          <a class="btn-primary"" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-04">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-4"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here.</p>
          <a class="btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.artibox {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  background-color: #888;
  background-image: none;
  color:#fff;
}

.artibox-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.artibox-container {
  height: 200px;
}

.artibox-title {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.artibox-intro {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  float: right;
}

.artibox-1 {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.koreaboo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/mamamoo-melting-4.jpg);
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.artibox-2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.asianjunkie.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/MAMAMOONewYork.jpg);
  background-position: 20% 20%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.artibox-3 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/F0V2Ctk.jpg);
  background-position: 20% 10%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.artibox-3 {
  background-image: url(http://www.allkpop.com/upload/2016/11/af_org/mamamoo_1478711828_af_org.jpg);
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.artibox-4 {
  background-image: url(http://img11.deviantart.net/4dd5/i/2016/075/4/3/mamamoo_png_by_euphoriclover-d9vbula.png);
  background-position: 0 10%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


#artibox-01:hover .artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#artibox-02:hover .artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#artibox-03:hover .artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
#artibox-04:hover .artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

My working file: http://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/RKrBgw

It is so troublesome if every time I update my file I need to add on the hover css like below:

```
#artibox-01:hover .artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Is there any way I can write in jquery as a function, so I no need to keep repeat the code? Thank you. Because I am very bad in jquery. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use purely CSS rule as

```
.artibox:hover .artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

instead of

```
#artibox-01:hover .artibox-hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNGqoG)

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is selector which fit to all `Id` that begin with "artibox-"

```
[id^="artibox-"]:hover .artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Moreover, as far as *" ...it only detects id but not class when I hover it"*  you can improve specificity of class selector by adding tag name:

```
div.artibox:hover div.artibox-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

this trick should affect on the target element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hover()` which binds one or two methods, first for when the mouse enters and the other for when the mouse leaves, and `find()` to find the element in `.artibox`.

```
$('.artibox').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.artibox-hover').css('opacity', '1');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.artibox-hover').css('opacity', '0');
});
```

See the working snippet below:

```js
$('.artibox').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.artibox-hover').css('opacity', '1');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.artibox-hover').css('opacity', '0');
});
```

```css
.artibox {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  background-color: #888;
  background-image: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.artibox-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.artibox-container {
  height: 200px;
}
.artibox-title {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
.artibox-intro {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  float: right;
}
.artibox-1 {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.koreaboo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/mamamoo-melting-4.jpg);
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.artibox-2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.asianjunkie.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/MAMAMOONewYork.jpg);
  background-position: 20% 20%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.artibox-3 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/F0V2Ctk.jpg);
  background-position: 20% 10%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.artibox-3 {
  background-image: url(http://www.allkpop.com/upload/2016/11/af_org/mamamoo_1478711828_af_org.jpg);
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.artibox-4 {
  background-image: url(http://img11.deviantart.net/4dd5/i/2016/075/4/3/mamamoo_png_by_euphoriclover-d9vbula.png);
  background-position: 0 10%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-01">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-1"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here.</p>
          <a class="btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-02">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-2"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here.</p>
          <a class="btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-03">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-3"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 3</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here</p>
          <a class="btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="artibox" id="artibox-04">
      <div class="artibox-hover artibox-4"></div>
      <div class="artibox-container container">
        <div class="artibox-title">
          <p class="artibox-date">Category</p>
          <h4>Title 4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="artibox-intro">
          <p class="artibox-excerpt">Content here.</p>
          <a class="btn-primary" href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can read more about the `hover()` method **[here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.artibox[id^="artibox-"]', function () {
  $(this).find('.artibox-hover').css('opacity', '1');
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.artibox[id^="artibox-"]', function () {
  $(this).find('.artibox-hover').css('opacity', '0');
});
```

You won't need the ":hover" css with this.